VNC into Ubuntu randomly showing screen tearing

As you can see above this is what happens when VNCing into my ubuntu box. It doesnt do it when I have a monitor attached.  Any help would be appreciated.

Are you able to determine the resolution that is configured with no screen attached? (e.g: fbset) Have you tried a "HDMI Ghost / Headless Display Adapter" in place of nothing or a screen?

@Attie resolution is 1024x768-76.  I have a monitor plugged in at the moment.  I dont use the monitor always as it is physically in a different location.
